# Svn repository projects location

Tags: svn, mod-dav-svn

I have a svn repository location in my apache httpd.conf file but when I search for my projects in that location I did not find any projects but when I checkout from client from that location I got all the projects.

Where are all these projects stored in the server?

Answer (score 0):

When you look through the contents of the `httpd.conf` file, you should find `SVNPath` or `SVNParentPath` directives. They will point to the [repositories](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.basics.html) on the server's filesystem. Note that you can not view repository contents with a regular file browser. You must use Subversion client tools for that.

If you maintain the Subversion server with Apache HTTP Server (mod_dav_svn) you should read the corresponding reference in the official documentation:

- [SVNBook | Server Configuration | httpd, the Apache HTTP Server](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html)

It is also going to be very helpful to read about Subversion and its concepts in the official documentation:

- [SVNBook | Fundamental Contepts](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.basic.html)